How can one determine if a reaction between a noble metal and an oxidizing acid will occur?
My current understading for the prediction of metal-acid reactivity is based on the concept of half-cells reduction potentials. I was taught that a generally good rule of thumb is that any metal whose half-cell reduction potential is negative (that is lower than the hydrogen half-cell) will readily react with basically any non-oxidizing acid (defined as a Bronsted-Lowry acid, whose anion has negligible oxidizing properties). Metals whose half-cells reduction potential is greater than the hydrogen's will defy such reactions - I will refer to those metals as noble metals.
We do know however that some noble metals can be dissolved by acids with sufficiently strong oxidizing properties such as HNO3 (supposedly regardless of molarity) or H2SO4 (in high molar concentration). I am looking for a way to conceptualize in conrete terms why anions such as NO3- or SO42- are capable of oxidizing certain noble metals.
Using reduction potentials for these two is troublesome, mainly because there are multiple different half-cells representing various ways in which these two can be reduced with different potential values attached to them (even in the same acid-base environment) and I am not sure which one to look at as my baseline for predictions (the one with the highest reduction pontetial?).
Also - what kind of predictions can or cannot be made using such potentials? For example, if I know that NO3- can undergo such reaction:
NO3- + 4H+ + 3e- ⇌ NO + H2O with Eo= 0.957V
Can I assume that HNO3 is capable of dissolving any metal with a reduction pontetial lower than the above value? How do we reconcile these predictions with the assumption that the aforementioned reduction potentials are standard reduction potentials which refer to 1M solutions of half-cell reagents (that is a system in which both NO3-, H+ and NO are present)?
Similar question goes for SO42-. My understanding is that in case of H2SO4 sufficiently concentrated solution is required for it to exibit oxidizing properties because we need to achieve certain concentration of SO42- anions as redox capabilities of chemical species is linked to their concentration. How can we measure this link however? I was trying to use Nernst equation and half-cells such as:
SO42- + 2H+ + 2e- ⇌ H2SO3 + H2O with Eo= 0.17V
...to find a minimal molarity of sulfuric acid that is required to oxidize say a given amount of bismuth, but since I am not trying to prepare a galvanic cell but I am simply putting a piece of metal in a flask containing just sulfuric acid I have no idea how to put the numbers together.
I feel that these particular tools - reduction potentials list and Nernst equation - are essentially useless in problems that I am trying to solve. The same question goes for non-oxidizing acids and active metals. How to calculate precisely the minimal molarity/set of conditions that are required for H+ to oxidize any particular metal? I recon that sufficiently concentrated non-oxidizing acid would be able to react even with a noble metal.
I ask for any sugestions and help with this! Thanks.

Check the Nernst equation for the half reactions involving the nitrate anion. You will rapidly understand that it reduction potential depends strongly on the pH and nitrate concentration.

@PAEP Understood! However if I have a metal plate that I'm inserting into nitric acid solution I do not have both halfcell components for the acid - ie. I have NO3- and H+ but no NO2 nor any other reduced species. How can I therefore use Nernst equation to predict the initial NO3- reduction potential?

You cannot make a quantitative prediction but you can estimate whether the reaction is spontaneous or not. As a rule of the thumb, you can use the standard reduction potentials or use Nernst's equation assuming the unknown concentration products have unit activity.
